# Multiple Scanner Inputs: Iterative validation of current selection blocks

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner

I am attempting to validate multiple scanner inputs with paired `If-Else` blocks in a single while loop. The behavior that I am interested in achieving is to the current validation `If-Statement` request the user to re-enter input or move on to the subsequent input / selection blocks.

Right now, I am using the `continue` keyword which returns to the beginning of the While loop. Would using a `do...while` loop be better suited for this? Thank you.

```
    while (count < numCars) {
        System.out.println("Enter car type");
        String name = scanner.next();
        if (name.matches(".*\\d")) {
            System.out.println("Name entry cannot contain numbers");
            continue;
        } else {
            // re-enter name
        }
        System.out.println("Enter max speed");
        int maxSpeed = scanner.nextInt();
        if (maxSpeed == 100 || maxSpeed > 100) {
            System.out.println("Max speed is not valid. Please re-enter");
            continue;
        } else {
            // re-enter age
            count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't quite get the objective of your code. Can you clarify a bit your question, please? When _count_ is updated? Why to _re-enter_ name/maxSpeed if the input is valid?

Comment: @LeoZa - if the input is valid, I wish to move to the next input block. However, if the input is not valid, I want to re-enter input for the specific block I am executing rather than return to the beginning of the while loop. The count was an error that I fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionality you want for every block can be achieved using `while` instead of `if-else` statements. I also structured your code in a nicer/more organized way:

```
int count = 0, numCars = 3;  // Example value
String name;
int maxSpeed;
        
while (count < numCars) {
    System.out.print("Enter car type: ");
    name = scanner.next();
    scanner.nextLine();     // Cleans the buffer
            
    while (name.matches(".*\\d")) {
        System.out.println("Name entry cannot contain numbers.");
        System.out.print("Enter car type: ");
        name = scanner.next();
        scanner.nextLine();     // Cleans the buffer
    }
            
    System.out.print("Enter max speed: ");
    maxSpeed = scanner.nextInt();

    while (maxSpeed >= 100) {
        System.out.println("Max speed is not valid. Please re-enter.");
        System.out.print("Enter max speed: ");
        maxSpeed = scanner.nextInt();
    }
            
    count++;      
}
```

Comment: This is a helpful solution. I was thought about nested while loops might work. Nice implementation... thanks for the solution!